# How do I remove one badly designed Solitaire game I installed?

Tags: xubuntu, software-center, uninstall

I installed a game called Solitaire on Xubuntu, but this game is very badly designed, so I decided to remove it.

Here is some useful info:

1. I installed this game using **Software** on Xubuntu, but the game is not found under the tab *Installed*.
2. I tried using **Ubuntu software center**, but still unable to find the game under the installed tab.
3. Using **Synaptic Package Manager** cannot locate the package of the game.

App icon:
[image: App icon]

App screenshot:
[image: App screenshot]

You can search "solitaire" on the "software" application of xubuntu, then you will find the game uploaded with the same icon as I have. Maybe you can successfully uninstall it.

---

#### Update

Output of `snap list`:

```
core        16-2.26.14        2462        canonical        - 
solitaire   1.0               2           1bsyl            -
```

Comment: What is the output of `snap list` command in Terminal?

Comment: core       16-2.26.14  2462  canonical  -
solitaire  1.0         2     1bsyl      -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have mentioned that the output of `snap list` is

```
core        16-2.26.14        2462        canonical        - 
solitaire   1.0               2           1bsyl            -
```

I suspect it's the installed `solitaire` snap package.

Try running the following command in Terminal:

```
snap remove solitaire
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!! I'm very new to Linux, and never knew there is something called "snap package" on Linux, interesting.